# How does the $http angular request pass the Spring Boot Security check?

Tags: angularjs, spring-security, spring-boot

I'm reading through this tutorial:

https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/

At I'm the point where the writer demonstrates that this does not work:

```
$ curl localhost:8080/resource
{"timestamp":1420442772928,"status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Full authentication is required to access this resource","path":"/resource"}
```

In the following section the author produces this snippet:

```
    angular.module('hello', [])
      .controller('home', function($http) {
      var self = this;
      $http.get('/resource/').then(function(response) {
        self.greeting = response.data;
      })
    });
```

And says that that is able to fetch the data.  My question is how does that snippet pass the security check?

TIA,
Ole

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read it again and realized that it uses basic authentication.  Spring Boot uses the user `user` and a password printed on the console or configured in `src/main/resources/application.properties` with a `security.user.password=password` entry.